# Filter an object by specific properties java

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

So I have this class:

```java
public class Seat {
    private Long id;
    private float positionX;
    private float positionY;
    private int numOfSeats;
    private String label;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I have `List` of `Seat` class on:

```java
List<Seat> seatList = // get data from repository;
```

I also have this `arraylist` contains list of ids:

```java
List<Long> idList; // for example : [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to filter `seatList` so that the filtered `ArrayList` does not contain a `Seat` object with id from `idList`, so I tried to use stream:

```java
List<Seat> filteredSeat = seatList.stream()
   .filter(seat -> {
         // function to filter seat.getId() so it would return the Seat object with id that does not equals to ids from idList
   })
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I cant find the correct function to do it. Does anyone have suggestion for me to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the overriden method from [`Collection#contains(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) with the negation implying the `id` was *not* found in the `List`.

```
Set<Seat> filteredSeat = seatList.stream()
    .filter(seat -> !idList.contains(seat.getId()))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Few notes:

- You want to use `Set<Long>` instead of `List<Long>` for an efficient look-up. Moreover, it doesn't make sense to have duplicate values among ids, so `Set` is a good choice.
- `Collectors.toSet()` results `Set`, so the Stream's return type is `Set<Seat>`.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution for be a for-each loop in which you check each idList against the Seat's id.

perhaps something like

```
List<Seat> FilteredList;
for ( Seat CurSeat : seatList ){
    for(int i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++){
```

and if the ID of CurSeat is part of idList, it doesn't get added to the new List.
This is definitely not the simplest way, but if you're looking for something easy, this is probably it.
Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you implement the `equals` method accordingly (like the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) mentions it), there is a much shorter solution:

```
seatList.stream()
   .distinct()
   .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```